# can't find img tag for jquery animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

While processing an image I'm trying to reduce the size of the current thumb using animate and apply an overlay.  The overlay is working but I can't seem to get animate working and I think it has something to do with the way I'm finding the image.

Here is the HTML:

```
<img id='loading' />
....

<tr>
    <td>
        <img id="5" src="<?php echo($url['url'])?>" style="height:120px;"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" id="img_5" class="test">Test Overlay</a></li>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
#loading { 
position: absolute; 
display: none;
background:transparent url(../../images/overlay.png) repeat top left;
}
```

My current click event looks like this:

```
    $('.test').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var loading_img = $('#loading');

        var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);

        var img = $('#' + id);        
        var pos = img.offset();

        var $image  = $('#' + id).find('img:first');

        $image.stop(true)
          .animate({
            'width' :img.width() - 10 + 'px',
            'height':img.height() - 10 + 'px',
          },250);

        loading_img.show().css({
            width: img.width(),
            height: img.height(),
            left:pos.left, 
            top:pos.top
        });
    });
```

Any idea what I'm missing with my animate call?

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected my example code. I have two unique ids but use the numerical piece to get the img id

Comment: Are you using the HTML5 doctype? (prior to HTML5 id's couldn't start with a numeric character.)

Comment: That was it! If I add text prior to the ID it works fine.

Comment: @Paul, you should go and tick the answer from where you got that overlay markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to HTML5 id's could not start with a numeric character. Without the HTML5 doctype, using such id's may not work in all browsers.